# Given X and Y are independent r.v. and U=X+Y, X~Chisq(a) and U~Chisq(b), how to find the distribution of Y?

Tags: joint-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Given $X$ and $Y$ are independent r.v. and $U=X+Y$, with $X\sim \mathcal{Chisq}(a)$ and $U \sim \mathcal{Chisq}(b)$, how to find the distribution of $Y$?

I know it is reasonable to guess $Y\sim \mathcal{chisq}(b-a)$ cuz it is easy to prove if $Y\sim \mathcal{chisq}(b-a)$ and $X\sim (a)$, then $X+Y\sim \mathcal{Chisq}(b)$, but how to find the distribution of $Y$ from given condition?

Comment: Of course you are talking about central chi-square random variables. Yes if Y is Chisq(b-a)   (where a and b are degrees of freedom).   U will be Chisq(b).  But is that the only way?

Comment: The original question asked about the mgf of Y so I guess this is where I'm supposeed to start with. But I cannot calculate the mgf directly since U and X seems dependent. Any hints? @MichaelChernick

Comment: Calculate the mgf (or better, the cf) of $U$ from those of $X$ and $Y$, then solve for the cf of $Y$.

Comment: But the given condition is the distribution of U and X... so how to calculate the mgf of Y from that? @whuber

Comment: Suppose I told you I had three numbers $x,y,u$ with $u=xy$ and that $x=3$ and $u=6$.  Would you present the same objection to a proposal to solve for $y$?  It's no different with cfs (or mgfs, assuming they are analytic).

Comment: Now I can see how to do that. So I can just use $E(e^{tx})E(e^{ty})$ = $E(e^{tu})$ then calculate the mgf of y am I getting it correctly? @whuber